# Vagrant - how do I get provision code to run before config.ssh.username = 'root'?

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to default the vm in my vagrant environment to log in as the root user. Code outside of my control must run as root and it can't be run using sudo (files are specifically copied to /root, etc.). The problem I am having is that vagrant seems to try to log in as root before the provision code is run (which copies the public key to the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file).

I have this line in the vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.username = 'root'
```

When I run vagrant up (clean env, so vm is freshly downloaded) I end up with this:

```
centos64: SSH username: root
centos64: SSH auth method: private key
centos64: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
centos64: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
centos64: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

If I ctrl-c out of this (or let it finally time out), it is clear that the provision code:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path = 'provision.sh'
  end
```

which does this:

```
mkdir /root/.ssh
touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
cat /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Has not been run.

But, if I comment out this line:

```
#config.ssh.username = 'root'
```

Then, run vagrant up (again, a clean install where the vm is downloaded from scratch), everything starts. Then I uncomment the line, and run vagrant up a second time, and I can ssh in as root, and I can see that the provision code has indeed been run(from the first vagrant up) and my key is in the authorized_keys file.

So, my question is this: How do I get the provision code to run before the config setting that tells it to use root to log in?

Comment: as a workaround, i think i will just put the vagrant keys in the /root/.ssh/authorized_users file on the box image, then use that .box file.